# json simple parser

Tags: java, json, parsing

**Hello**
I have a problem with a json simple parser. I have to parse something like this

```
{"phoneNumber":"9874662222","name":"Иван","surname":"Иванов","key":"ivanov0"}{"phoneNumber":"9874662222","name":"Иван","surname":"Иванов","key":"ivanov1"}{"phoneNumber":"9874662222","name":"Иван","surname":"Иванов","key":"ivanov2"}{"phoneNumber":"9874662222","name":"Иван","surname":"Иванов","key":"ivanov3"}{"phoneNumber":"9874662222","name":"Иван","surname":"Иванов","key":"ivanov4"}{"phoneNumber":"9874662222","name":"Иван","surname":"Иванов","key":"ivanov5"}{"phoneNumber":"9874662222","name":"Иван","surname":"Иванов","key":"ivanov6"}{"phoneNumber":"9874662222","name":"Иван","surname":"Иванов","key":"ivanov7"}{"phoneNumber":"9874662222","name":"Иван","surname":"Иванов","key":"ivanov8"}{"phoneNumber":"9874662222","name":"Иван","surname":"Иванов","key":"ivanov9"}
```

So I have many elements, what should I do?

Comment: You should provide some information on what you have tried to do and what the problem you are encountering is.

Comment: First, you should try *something*, and show us some code that does not work. Someone would then help you change it into code that works.

Comment: Note that your example is NOT valid JSON. You should tell more where it is coming from, what do you want to do with it and what does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read about how to deal with Strings in the programming language you need to work with. Learn about JSON, what it is and how a JSON statement is supposed to look like. Obviously, read about parsers too. Try to code something and then show us the code you've made.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you posted is not a JSON. It is list of JSON. Your question is not so clear but try to parse valid json in loop.